# Does tf.keras.layers.Conv1D support RaggedTensor input?

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network, ragged

In the tensorflow conv1D layer documentation, it says that;

> 'When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an
>   input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for
>   sequences of 10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors, or (None, 128) for
>   variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors.'

So I understand that we can input variable length sequences but when I use a ragged tensor input for conv1D layer, it gives me an error:

> ValueError: Layer conv1d does not support RaggedTensors as input.

What is really meant with variable length sequences if not RaggedTensors?

Thank you,

Comment: Initially I thought maybe you could have a [`Masking`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Masking) layer before and it would take that into account, but as far as I can see convolutional layers do not support masking (it is meant for RNN mainly). I think what that means in the documentation is that you can have batches with different sizes in the sequence length dimension. For example, in a dataset, [`padded_batch`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#padded_batch) can return batches with different shapes each time.

Comment: About ragged tensors, they do not seem to be supported, so your best bet is probably convert it to a regular tensor with [`to_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#to_tensor). You can later come back to ragged if you save the [`row_lengths`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#row_lengths) and pass the result to [`from_tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor#from_tensor).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have padded the ragged tensor and it worked.. But performance has significantly went down...

Comment: How do you mean? I thought you could not get it to run before. Performance went down with respect to what?

Comment: conv1D layer does not accept ragged tensors as input so I have padded it using tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences() first and now it is working. And sorry for the confusion, I meant it takes a lot longer now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Providing an answer here for the community, even if the answer is already present in the comment section.

`tf.keras.layers.Conv1D` does not support Ragged Tensors instead you can pad the sequences using `tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences` and use it as an input to the Conv1D layer.

Here is the example to pad_sequenes.

```
sequence = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequence)
```

> array([[0, 0, 1],[0, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)

You can also do a fixed-length padding, change the padding values, and post padding like below:

```
sequence = [[1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
tf.keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(sequence,maxlen=2,value=-1,padding="post")
```

> array([[ 1, -1],[ 2,  3],[ 5,  6]], dtype=int32)

Comment: can you please have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869272/raggedtensor-request-to-tensorflow-serving-fails ?